# How to shield the categories with Family Controls in iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I've implemented shielding apps with Family Controls.

But I don't know how to shield all categories app except the app selected by user in the FamilyActivityPicker?  Here is my code to shield apps and it worked. But I want to know if I could shield all apps and all "categories" except the apps user selected.  I want to allow only the apps and categories that user has selected.

```
let store = ManagedSettingsStore()
if let object = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "SelectedAppTokens") as? Data {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    if let appTokens = try? decoder.decode(Set<ApplicationToken>.self, from: object) {
        store.shield.applicationCategories = ShieldSettings.ActivityCategoryPolicy.all(except: appTokens)
    }
    
}
```

There is api to shield all "app" except user selected, but no "category"

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. I can get the Application Tokens from category when I set the option `includeEntireCategory` to true in FamilyActivitySelection.

like this

```
@State var selection = FamilyActivitySelection(includeEntireCategory: true)
```

If then, I can save the all application tokens(category include) selected by user.